# VS2015 Community Edition Crashes when starting: "Component Cache out of date"

Tags: c#, visual-studio

When VS2015 Community starts up it runs a MEF discovery.  Then after the application pops up it crashes.  I found entries like this in the component cache error log.  Any ideas on how to fix are much appreciated.

```
----- Catalog construction errors -----
Error #1
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Composition.PartDiscoveryException: Failure while scanning type "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.Razor.Implementation.Shims.RazorCodeGenerator+ParseData". ---> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Html.Editor, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
   at System.RuntimeTypeHandle.GetDeclaringType(RuntimeType type)
   at System.RuntimeType.RuntimeTypeCache.GetEnclosingType()
   at System.RuntimeType.get_DeclaringType()
   at System.Type.get_IsNested()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Composition.AttributedPartDiscovery.CreatePart(Type partType, Boolean typeExplicitlyRequested)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Composition.PartDiscovery.CombinedPartDiscovery.CreatePart(Type partType, Boolean typeExplicitlyRequested)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Composition.PartDiscovery.<>c__DisplayClass25_0.<CreateDiscoveryBlockChain>b__0(Type type)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
Error #2
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Composition.PartDiscoveryException: Failure while scanning type "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.Razor.Implementation.Shims.RazorCodeGenerator+<>c__DisplayClass30_0". ---> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Html.Editor, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
   at System.RuntimeTypeHandle.GetDeclaringType(RuntimeType type)
   at System.RuntimeType.RuntimeTypeCache.GetEnclosingType()
   at System.RuntimeType.get_DeclaringType()
   at System.Type.get_IsNested()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Composition.AttributedPartDiscovery.CreatePart(Type partType, Boolean typeExplicitlyRequested)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Composition.PartDiscovery.CombinedPartDiscovery.CreatePart(Type partType, Boolean typeExplicitlyRequested)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Composition.PartDiscovery.<>c__DisplayClass25_0.<CreateDiscoveryBlockChain>b__0(Type type)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
Error #3
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Composition.PartDiscoveryException: Failure while scanning type "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.Razor.Implementation.Shims.RazorCodeGenerator+<>c". ---> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Html.Editor, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
   at System.RuntimeTypeHandle.GetDeclaringType(RuntimeType type)
   at System.RuntimeType.RuntimeTypeCache.GetEnclosingType()
   at System.RuntimeType.get_DeclaringType()
   at System.Type.get_IsNested()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Composition.AttributedPartDiscovery.CreatePart(Type partType, Boolean typeExplicitlyRequested)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Composition.PartDiscovery.CombinedPartDiscovery.CreatePart(Type partType, Boolean typeExplicitlyRequested)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Composition.PartDiscovery.<>c__DisplayClass25_0.<CreateDiscoveryBlockChain>b__0(Type type)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
Error #4
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Composition.PartDiscoveryException: ReflectionTypeLoadException while enumerating types in assembly "C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.HTML.Razor.Implementation.Shims.3_0\v4.0_14.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.HTML.Razor.Implementation.Shims.3_0.dll". Results will be incomplete. ---> System.Reflection.ReflectionTypeLoadException: Unable to load one or more of the requested types. Retrieve the LoaderExceptions property for more information.
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeModule.GetTypes(RuntimeModule module)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeModule.GetTypes()
   at System.Reflection.Assembly.GetTypes()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Composition.PartDiscovery.CombinedPartDiscovery.GetTypes(Assembly assembly)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Composition.PartDiscovery.<>c__DisplayClass26_0.<CreateAssemblyDiscoveryBlockChain>b__0(Assembly a)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Html.Editor, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
File name: 'Microsoft.Html.Editor, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'

WRN: Assembly binding logging is turned OFF.
To enable assembly bind failure logging, set the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog] (DWORD) to 1.
Note: There is some performance penalty associated with assembly bind failure logging.
To turn this feature off, remove the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog].

System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Html.Editor, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
File name: 'Microsoft.Html.Editor, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'

WRN: Assembly binding logging is turned OFF.
To enable assembly bind failure logging, set the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog] (DWORD) to 1.
Note: There is some performance penalty associated with assembly bind failure logging.
To turn this feature off, remove the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog].

System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Html.Editor, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
File name: 'Microsoft.Html.Editor, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'

WRN: Assembly binding logging is turned OFF.
To enable assembly bind failure logging, set the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog] (DWORD) to 1.
Note: There is some performance penalty associated with assembly bind failure logging.
To turn this feature off, remove the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog].

System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Html.Editor, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
File name: 'Microsoft.Html.Editor, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'

WRN: Assembly binding logging is turned OFF.
To enable assembly bind failure logging, set the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog] (DWORD) to 1.
Note: There is some performance penalty associated with assembly bind failure logging.
To turn this feature off, remove the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog].

Error #5
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Composition.PartDiscoveryException: ReflectionTypeLoadException while enumerating types in assembly "C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO 14.0\COMMON7\IDE\EXTENSIONS\MICROSOFT\WINDOWS AZURE TOOLS\SERVICES\Microsoft.VisualStudio.WindowsAzure.Services.WebExtensions.dll". Results will be incomplete. ---> System.Reflection.ReflectionTypeLoadException: Unable to load one or more of the requested types. Retrieve the LoaderExceptions property for more information.
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeModule.GetTypes(RuntimeModule module)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeModule.GetTypes()
   at System.Reflection.Assembly.GetTypes()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Composition.PartDiscovery.CombinedPartDiscovery.GetTypes(Assembly assembly)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Composition.PartDiscovery.<>c__DisplayClass26_0.<CreateAssemblyDiscoveryBlockChain>b__0(Assembly a)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.AspNet.Scaffolding.12.0, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
File name: 'Microsoft.AspNet.Scaffolding.12.0, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'

WRN: Assembly binding logging is turned OFF.
To enable assembly bind failure logging, set the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog] (DWORD) to 1.
Note: There is some performance penalty associated with assembly bind failure logging.
To turn this feature off, remove the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog].

System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.AspNet.Scaffolding.12.0, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
File name: 'Microsoft.AspNet.Scaffolding.12.0, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'

WRN: Assembly binding logging is turned OFF.
To enable assembly bind failure logging, set the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog] (DWORD) to 1.
Note: There is some performance penalty associated with assembly bind failure logging.
To turn this feature off, remove the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog].

System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.AspNet.Scaffolding.12.0, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
File name: 'Microsoft.AspNet.Scaffolding.12.0, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'

WRN: Assembly binding logging is turned OFF.
To enable assembly bind failure logging, set the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog] (DWORD) to 1.
Note: There is some performance penalty associated with assembly bind failure logging.
To turn this feature off, remove the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog].

System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.AspNet.Scaffolding.12.0, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
File name: 'Microsoft.AspNet.Scaffolding.12.0, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'

WRN: Assembly binding logging is turned OFF.
To enable assembly bind failure logging, set the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog] (DWORD) to 1.
Note: There is some performance penalty associated with assembly bind failure logging.
To turn this feature off, remove the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog].

System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.AspNet.Scaffolding.12.0, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
File name: 'Microsoft.AspNet.Scaffolding.12.0, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'

WRN: Assembly binding logging is turned OFF.
To enable assembly bind failure logging, set the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog] (DWORD) to 1.
Note: There is some performance penalty associated with assembly bind failure logging.
To turn this feature off, remove the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog].

System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.AspNet.Scaffolding.12.0, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
File name: 'Microsoft.AspNet.Scaffolding.12.0, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'

WRN: Assembly binding logging is turned OFF.
To enable assembly bind failure logging, set the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog] (DWORD) to 1.
Note: There is some performance penalty associated with assembly bind failure logging.
To turn this feature off, remove the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog].

System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.AspNet.Scaffolding.12.0, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
File name: 'Microsoft.AspNet.Scaffolding.12.0, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'

WRN: Assembly binding logging is turned OFF.
To enable assembly bind failure logging, set the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog] (DWORD) to 1.
Note: There is some performance penalty associated with assembly bind failure logging.
To turn this feature off, remove the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog].

System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.AspNet.Scaffolding.12.0, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
File name: 'Microsoft.AspNet.Scaffolding.12.0, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'

WRN: Assembly binding logging is turned OFF.
To enable assembly bind failure logging, set the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog] (DWORD) to 1.
Note: There is some performance penalty associated with assembly bind failure logging.
To turn this feature off, remove the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog].

System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.AspNet.Scaffolding.12.0, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
File name: 'Microsoft.AspNet.Scaffolding.12.0, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'

WRN: Assembly binding logging is turned OFF.
To enable assembly bind failure logging, set the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog] (DWORD) to 1.
Note: There is some performance penalty associated with assembly bind failure logging.
To turn this feature off, remove the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog].

System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.AspNet.Scaffolding.12.0, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
File name: 'Microsoft.AspNet.Scaffolding.12.0, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'

WRN: Assembly binding logging is turned OFF.
To enable assembly bind failure logging, set the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog] (DWORD) to 1.
Note: There is some performance penalty associated with assembly bind failure logging.
To turn this feature off, remove the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog].

Error #6
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Composition.PartDiscoveryException: Failure while scanning type "Microsoft.VisualStudio.MultiDeviceHybridApps.VSPackages.ServiceManager.XPlatAzureMobileServiceHandler". ---> System.ArgumentException: An element with the same key but a different value already exists. Key: AppliesTo
   at System.Collections.Immutable.ImmutableDictionary`2.HashBucket.Add(TKey key, TValue value, IEqualityComparer`1 keyOnlyComparer, IEqualityComparer`1 valueComparer, KeyCollisionBehavior behavior, OperationResult& result)
   at System.Collections.Immutable.ImmutableDictionary`2.Add(TKey key, TValue value, KeyCollisionBehavior behavior, MutationInput origin)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Composition.AttributedPartDiscoveryV1.GetExportMetadata(ICustomAttributeProvider member)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Composition.AttributedPartDiscoveryV1.CreatePart(Type partType, Boolean typeExplicitlyRequested)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Composition.PartDiscovery.CombinedPartDiscovery.CreatePart(Type partType, Boolean typeExplicitlyRequested)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Composition.PartDiscovery.<>c__DisplayClass25_0.<CreateDiscoveryBlockChain>b__0(Type type)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
Error #7
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Composition.PartDiscoveryException: Failure while scanning type "Microsoft.VisualStudio.MultiDeviceHybridApps.VSPackages.ServiceManager.XPlatConnectedServiceHandlerHelper". ---> System.ArgumentException: An element with the same key but a different value already exists. Key: AppliesTo
   at System.Collections.Immutable.ImmutableDictionary`2.HashBucket.Add(TKey key, TValue value, IEqualityComparer`1 keyOnlyComparer, IEqualityComparer`1 valueComparer, KeyCollisionBehavior behavior, OperationResult& result)
   at System.Collections.Immutable.ImmutableDictionary`2.Add(TKey key, TValue value, KeyCollisionBehavior behavior, MutationInput origin)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Composition.AttributedPartDiscoveryV1.GetExportMetadata(ICustomAttributeProvider member)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Composition.AttributedPartDiscoveryV1.CreatePart(Type partType, Boolean typeExplicitlyRequested)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Composition.PartDiscovery.CombinedPartDiscovery.CreatePart(Type partType, Boolean typeExplicitlyRequested)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Composition.PartDiscovery.<>c__DisplayClass25_0.<CreateDiscoveryBlockChain>b__0(Type type)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
Error #8
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Composition.PartDiscoveryException: ReflectionTypeLoadException while enumerating types in assembly "C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.VisualStudio.JavaScript.Project\v4.0_14.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.VisualStudio.JavaScript.Project.dll". Results will be incomplete. ---> System.Reflection.ReflectionTypeLoadException: Unable to load one or more of the requested types. Retrieve the LoaderExceptions property for more information.
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeModule.GetTypes(RuntimeModule module)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeModule.GetTypes()
   at System.Reflection.Assembly.GetTypes()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Composition.PartDiscovery.CombinedPartDiscovery.GetTypes(Assembly assembly)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Composition.PartDiscovery.<>c__DisplayClass26_0.<CreateAssemblyDiscoveryBlockChain>b__0(Assembly a)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.CSS.Editor, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
File name: 'Microsoft.CSS.Editor, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'

WRN: Assembly binding logging is turned OFF.
To enable assembly bind failure logging, set the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog] (DWORD) to 1.
Note: There is some performance penalty associated with assembly bind failure logging.
To turn this feature off, remove the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog].

System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.CSS.Editor, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
File name: 'Microsoft.CSS.Editor, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'

WRN: Assembly binding logging is turned OFF.
To enable assembly bind failure logging, set the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog] (DWORD) to 1.
Note: There is some performance penalty associated with assembly bind failure logging.
To turn this feature off, remove the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog].

Error #9
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Composition.PartDiscoveryException: Failure while scanning type "GitHub.Services.TeamExplorerServices". ---> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Controls, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
   at System.Signature.GetSignature(Void* pCorSig, Int32 cCorSig, RuntimeFieldHandleInternal fieldHandle, IRuntimeMethodInfo methodHandle, RuntimeType declaringType)
   at System.Signature..ctor(IRuntimeFieldInfo fieldHandle, RuntimeType declaringType)
   at System.Reflection.RtFieldInfo.get_FieldType()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Composition.ReflectionHelpers.GetMemberType(MemberInfo fieldOrPropertyOrType)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Composition.AttributedPartDiscoveryV1.AddImportsFromMembers(PropertyInfo[] declaredProperties, FieldInfo[] declaredFields, TypeRef partTypeRef, IList`1 imports)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Composition.AttributedPartDiscoveryV1.CreatePart(Type partType, Boolean typeExplicitlyRequested)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Composition.PartDiscovery.CombinedPartDiscovery.CreatePart(Type partType, Boolean typeExplicitlyRequested)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Composition.PartDiscovery.<>c__DisplayClass25_0.<CreateDiscoveryBlockChain>b__0(Type type)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
Error #10
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Composition.PartDiscoveryException: Failure while scanning type "GitHub.Services.VSServices". ---> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Git.Provider, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
   at System.Signature.GetSignature(Void* pCorSig, Int32 cCorSig, RuntimeFieldHandleInternal fieldHandle, IRuntimeMethodInfo methodHandle, RuntimeType declaringType)
   at System.Signature..ctor(IRuntimeFieldInfo fieldHandle, RuntimeType declaringType)
   at System.Reflection.RtFieldInfo.get_FieldType()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Composition.ReflectionHelpers.GetMemberType(MemberInfo fieldOrPropertyOrType)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Composition.AttributedPartDiscoveryV1.AddImportsFromMembers(PropertyInfo[] declaredProperties, FieldInfo[] declaredFields, TypeRef partTypeRef, IList`1 imports)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Composition.AttributedPartDiscoveryV1.CreatePart(Type partType, Boolean typeExplicitlyRequested)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Composition.PartDiscovery.CombinedPartDiscovery.CreatePart(Type partType, Boolean typeExplicitlyRequested)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Composition.PartDiscovery.<>c__DisplayClass25_0.<CreateDiscoveryBlockChain>b__0(Type type)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
Error #11
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Composition.PartDiscoveryException: Failure while scanning type "GitHub.VisualStudio.Base.TeamExplorerNavigationItemBase+<Invalidate>d__2". ---> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Controls, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
   at System.RuntimeTypeHandle.GetDeclaringType(RuntimeType type)
   at System.RuntimeType.RuntimeTypeCache.GetEnclosingType()
   at System.RuntimeType.get_DeclaringType()
   at System.Type.get_IsNested()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Composition.AttributedPartDiscovery.CreatePart(Type partType, Boolean typeExplicitlyRequested)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Composition.PartDiscovery.CombinedPartDiscovery.CreatePart(Type partType, Boolean typeExplicitlyRequested)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Composition.PartDiscovery.<>c__DisplayClass25_0.<CreateDiscoveryBlockChain>b__0(Type type)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
```

And on and on...

Comment: you might try `devenv.exe /installvstemplates` or `devenv.exe /resetskippkgs`

Comment: @Claies Thanks for suggestion... didn't work...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I never found the root cause; however, I was able to get it running... check this link:

[Visual Studio 2015 community edition crashes at startup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37955710/visual-studio-2015-community-edition-crashes-at-startup/38025948#38025948)